# Transparent button on Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: button, transparent, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been wrestling with this for a while and I can't seem to figure it out.  Maybe someone here has dealt with something similar.

I'm trying to place a button on top of my Google map and have the button be transparent.

Here's what I've written, but no luck:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:keepScreenOn="true" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:alpha=".30"
        android:text="@string/button1_label"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, if you see anything wrong with my code,  feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:alpha was added in API 11. Use your own transparent background image (or a set of images in statelist).

If this doesn't help, post the screenshot. This can make answering easier.

Comment: Yes I think that's the reason for it not working.  Using transparent images work though, so I'll ring up a statelist and see if that doesn't do the trick.  Thanks again Macie!